# Using a custom window with ajax form to add new grid row

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-window

I need to create a more advanced method of adding new elements to a kendo grid, so in short I have replicated the following example as it does exactly what I needed:
https://github.com/telerik/ui-for-aspnet-mvc-examples/tree/master/window/KendoWindow-Ajax-Form

And it works just fine. Only difference is the new row is added in it's correct spot in the grid, and not on the top as per usual. How can I, using the example linked to, place the new row on the top?

(I'm thinking it's not necessary to show my code here as it very closely resembles the code given in the link above)

Comment: why not just order the data based on descending created date? this way whenever new data is created they will always appear on top

Comment: @mylee I have written af response to Cobaltsfive that explains the issue more clearly.

Comment: If you want the new records to appear on top just when the user has created it then you should use the kendo dataSource.pushCreate function. When the user refresh the page it will go back to its correct spot instead of the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up finding the solution myself eventually. Going by the example in the link I made in the original post, this is what I did:
Firstly when a new "order" is made, I make sure that the model returned in the "Create" method in OrdersDataController has an ID from when the model is added to the DB.
So when this part gets executed in "_OrdersCreate.cshtml":

```
@if (Model != null && ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    <script>
        closeCreatePopup();
    </script>
}
```

I send information on the new Order created. So to that end I have modified "closeCreatePopup()" to handle arguments.
So for the finished results I will just use a piece of code from my own project, the following is my implementation of "closeCreatePopup()":

```
function closeCreateEmployeeWindow(name, rHPersonID, personID, organizationID) {
    if (name !== undefined
        && rHPersonID !== undefined
        && personID !== undefined
        && organizationID !== undefined) {

        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.dataSource.insert({ Name: name, RHPersonID: rHPersonID, PersonID: personID, OrganizationID: organizationID });
        grid.dataSource.sync();
    }

    var wnd = $("#createEmployeeModal").data("kendoWindow");
    wnd.refresh({ url: '@Url.Action("CreateEmployee", "Employee", new { Area = "Administration" })' });
    wnd.close();
}
```

The important part is this:

```
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.insert({ Name: name, RHPersonID: rHPersonID, PersonID: personID, OrganizationID: organizationID });
grid.dataSource.sync();
```

What is happening here is I use the "insert" method from the grid, and add a new object. "Insert" inserts the new object to the very top of the grid. Remember to call the "sync" method right after.

By doing it like this, the normal "create" method built into the grid is replicated.

Answer (score 0):

So If you want to add a row up top I am thinking you could use a custom template. I may not be very clear on what you are doing but , I will attempt to help you.
Here is the grid in the code:`

```
     @(Html.Kendo().Grid<OrderViewModel>()

                    .Name("grid")
                    .Columns(columns =>
                     {
                      columns.Bound(c => c.Message).EditorTemplateName("MessageEditor");
                     }
                    .DataSource(datasource => datasource

                        .Ajax()

                        .Read(read => read.Action("GetOrders", "OrdersData"))



                )

                )`
```

Then write the template like this:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="MessageEditor">
    <div class="k-header k-grid-toolbar">

        <div style="display: inline-block; font-size:1.25em; padding: 
        </div>
    </div>

</script>
```

Well this may not be the best solution , however it is the only way I know to create a custom column in a Kendo grid

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't know I was clear enough now that I think about it, but to reiterate; by using an ordinary create function in a kendo grid, the newest item you added is added to the very top of the row, but this is just in the DOM. If you refresh the grid, the list is retrieved from the server and then ordered as such.
Using the method I linked to, the new item is not added to the top, because it does not use the built in create method of the grid. Therefore the issue.

Comment: Hi sir, If I am correct all you need is for the list returned from the database to be in order of the most recent created. We do this by using a date created field in our database, like Mylee stated above. You can just order by the date created. Here is the kendo official server sorting information I use hope it helps: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/serversorting